# menu on rightside and Logo on left in a semi-transparent navigation bar

Tags: html, css

I need a navbar which is semi transparent over the background image.

Logo on left side and menu on right-side which should be equally spaced between list items.Something like -

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/cover/

http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/full-screen-background-cover-page

I tried giving `float:right` to my `<ul>` element of menulist, it goes to the right extreme.

HTML

```
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul style="float:right;">
        <li style="display:inline;"><a href= "#">item1</a></li>
        <li style="display:inline;"><a href= "#">item2</a></li>
        <li style="display:inline;"><a href= "#">item3</a></li>
        <li style="display:inline;"><a href= "#">item4</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
 background-image:url("giphy.gif");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 overflow-x:hidden;
}

nav {
  height:60px;
  width:100%; 
  overflow-y:hidden;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  z-index:1;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

Comment: make the logo an element with a bg image instead of putting it on the body element, that way it will be easier to move the element around the page with css.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/ruwopuyavu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0):

Using Bootstrap css, You can do it as

```
<body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Your LOGO here.</a>
        </div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="float:right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li> 
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li> 
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Hope this helps!